# Preselecting values in select elements

Tags: html, forms, templates, select

I run into this scenario *all* the time:  I need to prepopulate an HTML `select` element *in a template* based on some existing data, but I've found no "good" way to do so.  This problem exists with both client- and server-side templates, but for the moment I'll use server-side code for my example:

The data:

```
<?php
$person = [
    'name' => 'Bob',
    'gender' => 'm'
];
```

The template:

```
<!-- easy peasy -->
<input name="name" type="text" value="<?= $person['name'] ?>">

<!-- not so easy! -->
<select name="gender">
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
</select>
```

Since a `select` element's value is determined by the `selected` attribute of one (or many) child `option` elements, it's deceptively hard to preselect a value.  You can litter your template with conditions, like this:

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="m"<?= $person['gender'] === 'm' ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="f"<?= $person['gender'] === 'f' ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

...but this is bad for many reasons, not the least of which is that it becomes downright painful with longer options lists.

You can also leave it up to the client to populate the value, with a little voodoo:

```
<select name="gender" data-value="<?= $person['gender'] ?>">
    <!-- ... -->
</select>

<script>
    // ...
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).data('value'));
    });
</script>
```

...but this method, while concise, is completely reliant on JS and problematic in its own right.

**So, my question is:** how do you accomplish this task?  Do you completely sidestep it by decoupling data from the template?  Or maybe some trick I've never come across before?

Comment: So .. I don't get what exactly is your problem? You are trying to echo a long select list from which one element is selected, right? Why not use <foreach():> clause ?

Comment: @AvnerSolomon: I am not echoing the HTML.  The HTML is a template.

Comment: Yes .. but isn't that a PHP template? or what template system are you using?

Comment: I mean in most templating languages you have foreach structure. If you are using CodeIgniter the templating language is PHP for example and u can

`<selected>
 <?php foreach($array as $key=>$value):?>
  <option value="<?=$key?>" <?=$value?> </option>
 <?php endforeach;?>
</selected>
`
and the selected would be an if. But all this depends on your templating language. Also there are client-side templating lang like handlebars.js or dust.js and many more. (ofc that takes a tall on the client)

Comment: @AvnerSolomon: Your example puts logic in the template.  I'm trying to only use data (or *minimal* logic, where necessary - but markup-generating loops aren't exactly minimal logic).

Comment: most templates languages have causal and something like foreach. You can't implement it otherwise